# Sequential Delivery of Binary Payload using Apache Camel Integration?

Tags: apache-camel, cxf, sequence, fuseesb

I have requirement to send files sequentially as they come. For instance if there are three binary files F1, F2 and F2 and they come in order F1, F2 and F3. It must be delivery in same sequence i.e. F1, F2 and F3. It works in happy workflow.

But, when delivery of F1 fails due to network glitch this sequencing breaks.

**My Research So Far:**

1. We can keep retrying until problem is resolved: **Not A Good Design**
2. Make process synchronous and send success or fail to source system then , source system will send next payload or same payload. It cost performance and involvement of other system.

**Also, just for information - How basic current flow works?**

Source System Sends binary data using REST Client to Our Rest Service and We send connect to FTP Server and send that binary payload to require folder.

Comment below if more information required.

Comment: if you make this process async. How you can guarantee that F1 will be delivered first?

Comment: Sorry, I mean to say sync. I will update question.

Comment: To send messages in sequence you need some id. How did you know the F1 sent is the F1 for this batch and not the one intended 2 hours ago? You will need to identify the messages, store the messages in some temporary queue (activemq) and once three sequences match then send to FTP server. If something breaks, keep them on the temp queue until the missing one arrives.

Answer (score 0):

You have a logically incompatible set of functional requirements. You want order maintained, but also indicate that "1. We can keep retrying until problem is resolved: Not A Good Design".

It is tough to have both. Also, sending to a REST endpoint is inherently async and order should not be presumed when two messages are sent to a REST endpoint.

I suggest a single threaded polling consumer, and in your error handler send out a notification of error.